# Close a window ,created with window.open(), with window.close() in an asynchronous way doesn't work in Firefox and Edge

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser

In this simple code I open a new tab with `window.open()`, later I wait 5 seconds and in asynchronous way (because the URL loaded should be loaded in an asynchronous way) I want close the new created window. The code works in Google Chroome, but it doesn't close the window in Firefox and Edge. What is the problem?

Edit: I added an if else in the asynchronous code and testing the `closed` property, the new window results already closed but in fact it isn't the case.
Furthermore should be possible close pages created from the script with `window.open()`, however I tried also to set about:config dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows  from false to true , but nothing the problem remains

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Prova</title>
   <style>
      body{
         margin:0;

      }

      p{
         float:right;
         width:20%;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Hello</p>                                                                                              

   <script>

      //sleep delay seconds
      async function sleep(delay){
         return new Promise((resolve)=>setTimeout(resolve,delay*1000));
      }

      let mywindow = window.open("https://www.google.com","mypage");
      async function closeWindow(){
      await sleep(5);
      if(mywindow.closed) //This result true
         console.log("The window seems already closed");
      else
      mywindow.close();
      }
      closeWindow();


   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit:
It doesn't even work with an event-handler. I get rid await/Promise to see if the problem was there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Prova</title>
   <style>
      body{
         margin:0;

      }

      p{
         float:right;
         width:20%;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Hello</p>                                                                                              
<button onclick="closeWindow();">Chiudi</button>
   <script>



      let mywindow = window.open("https://www.ubuntu-it.org/","mypage");

      function closeWindow(){

      if(mywindow.closed) //This result true
         console.log("The window seems already closed");
      else
      mywindow.close();
      }



   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**: Both the above codes work,also in my Firefox browser, when the parent page and the child page have the same origin(protocol+port+domain), i.e. for example if both are two my local pages. In this case the 2 pages have 2 different origins (local page and   https://www.google.com).
However [MDN cross-origin-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)
in section *Window* says: `close()` should works in the cross-origin case like the mine. Indeed other people with my same browser Firefox version are able to run successfully the same code with cross-origin-policy limitation with whom I'am in troubles.    Thus is there a workaround, setting problem, security policy, where I can to intervene to resolve the problem?

Comment: your code works just fine in firefox

Comment: @JaromandaX My browser is Firefox 76.0.1  64 bit for Ubuntu.   I confirm the problem, the window opens but is not closed after the sleep

Comment: it would be unusual for firefox to behave differently in ubuntu than, say, windows, but I guess you never know what ubuntu do to their firefox

Comment: I can assure you your code works in Windows 10 Firefox

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried in Windows 10. At the beginning I tried Firefox 71 and "mywindow" is equal to null thereby I had a TypeError. Later I updated to 76.0.1 and I got the same behavior of Ubuntu namely after 5 seconds "mywindow.closed results true" and the new window isn't closed. In Edge I observed the same problem of Firefox 76.0.1 (I tried IE11 too but there I had problems with popup settings, never mind). So there is some more subtle problem below.   What is your Firefox version?

Comment: 76.0.1 and 77.0b7

Comment: Unbelievable. Then could be something in the settings. I can't figure what is the problem

Comment: it doesn't work until you allow popups of course, so the first time, by the time you've allowed the popups it's too late, but refresh the page and it works ... in firefox and edge (the chrome version, no idea about the microsoft version)  and chrome

Comment: I allowed the popups so that doesn't ask me permission anymore (however I had already tried to refresh), I think it isn't this the problem. With Chroome works both Ubuntu and Microsoft 10. With Firefox no in boths  the SO.

Comment: @JaromandaX I modified my answer, the code works if the two page have the same origin.  But close() method  should works with cross-origin-policy too, but it isn't the case for me. Why?

Comment: and there's nothing in the developer tools console at all?

Comment: There is the message : `The window seems already closed`  and a warning: Automatically allowed access to storage resources for tracer element "https://www.google.com" on "null".